# Pyinstaller: Creating an Executable with Several Dependencies - "TypeError"

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, wxpython, pyinstaller, objectlistview-python

I have a fairly large wx application I have built and would like to compile it into a executable file. I have done this before, however, the process has become more complicated because I am working with several other dependencies (packages) and my program is composed of multiple .py files. Before I post the code, I'll describe the initial error message.

**Error Message**

I navigate to the directory where all my script files are saved and execute the following command in the prompt (cmd) window:

> pyinstaller -F AMI_GUI.py

Pyinstaller initially runs okay however at the end of process I get this error:

> TypeError: iteration over non-sequence

I have posted a screen shot to better show this error.

[image: First Pyinstaller Attempt Gets ValueTypeError]

What is interesting is what happens next, I try running the same command again, 'pyinstaller -F AMI_GUI.py'. But this time the error does not occur, instead the process finishes and in my ***dist*** directory my executable has been created. I am also able to run the executable.

[image: Run Pyinstaller a second time. No Error!]

Has anyone ran into this problem before when compiling applications using pyinstaller? I have not done extensive testing on the executable file yet, but I am worried in trusting it because pyinstaller process failed on the first time.

I have posted part of my code which shows the dependencies and some of my code:

***AMI_GUI.py***

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Integer, String, DateTime, Float, UnicodeText, VARCHAR, NVARCHAR, TEXT, DATE, distinct, ForeignKey, Table,or_,and_
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, relationship
import math
import wx
import wx.lib.mixins.listctrl  as  listmix
from ObjectListView import ObjectListView, ColumnDefn
from ObjectListView import EVT_CELL_EDIT_STARTING
from ObjectListView import EVT_CELL_EDIT_FINISHING
import os
import time

from wigets import File_Manager,Date_Filter,Log_In,EVT_LOGIN
from AMI_component import engine
from AMI_component import Exception,Meter,Transformer,except_heading,meter_heading
import csv

## Link to Database
Session = sessionmaker( bind=engine )                   ## Import the database engine from component file
session = Session()                                     ## Create session to database
```

***AMI_components.py***

```
import os,math,random,string,operator,logging,csv
from itertools import count

from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Integer, String, DateTime, Float, UnicodeText, VARCHAR, NVARCHAR, TEXT, DATE, distinct, ForeignKey, Table
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, relationship
from AMI_subroutine import getFiles,incident_filt,getDB,get_manf,dayMonth,check_voltage,violation_filt,rec,get_dateTime
admin_dir = "C:\project\AMI"
# print os.getcwd()
os.chdir(admin_dir)

engine = create_engine("sqlite:///./AMI_case.db", #"oracle://rai:raisys@njnwkora18_oraa.db.pseg.com",
                       echo=False)

Session = sessionmaker( bind=engine )
session = Session()
```

Not sure if this code will help, but it does show how what import statements I have used...the some of the main file that I am running with the pyinstall command is AMI_GUI.py.

Comment: Never used pyinstaller (using py2exe for freezing), but to me it looks like a pyinstaller issue, don't see why you list the others.

Comment: Well, I was thinking it had something ot do with the depenedencies, maybe something someone who has created executables using the packages wx, sqlalh, etc has run into those issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did a bit of googling, it definitely looks like a pyinstaller bug.

See:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pyinstaller/lDCzhTS4Apo

https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/964